# Install and run Java app on Ubuntu 14.04 issue

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, java, jdk, openjdk

I want to run just [Selenium Standalone Server](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) on Ubuntu 14.04.

I had the same issue withopenjdk-8-jdk installation, but [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/a/746429) solved it.

Now I have another problem, I can't just run the Java app.

```
~/workspace/php-web-driver-test $ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openqa/grid/selenium/GridLauncherV3 : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:442)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:64)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:312)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes openjdk doesn't work but oracle java does. Try installing it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

and then run

```
sudo apt update&&sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
```

If this doesn't work then the software might not be compatible and you might want to try different versions or other software

Comment: Does ppa:webupd8team/java still work for installing oracle-java8-installer? According to several recent questions ppa:webupd8team/java does not work anymore for installing oracle-java8-installer because the link to the official Oracle website in oracle-java8-installer is broken and the software hasn't been updated. If you tested the command in your answer and it works I would like to know it, because if oracle-java8-installer has been updated, then one of my answers needs to be updated too.

Comment: @Bitblocks Thanks, now it's working. Same [description](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/) as in answer.

Comment: Your welcome. I don't know much about java but I knew from research that openjdk doesn't work as well as Oracle Java. Glad I could help! :)